# being able to store price history

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a project at the moment, let's say is a groceries store.

The price of milk is not always the same, and I have a model Product, with products_controller and all the views I need to edit, delete etc.

However, I would also like to be able to see what was the price of milk, say a month ago. With a simple edit, I'm just editing the production item, but I'm losing the history.

Is there any way to implement, probably in another model, where I would have price, active_date and inactive_date, so when I edit something it automatically creates a record in my history table deactivating the current item.

Maybe there's even a gem out there to help manage this?

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the [acts_as_audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited) gem might do what you want.

Comment: OK, just tried it and it didn't quite do what I needed. It did record the fact that there was a change in the value, but nothing else useful. I just have how many versions the item has and the user. But it doesn;t show me what the previous value was. Is this something I can capture?

Comment: Hmmm - sorry.  It looks like you're right about that.  Could you make a model that represents product audit records (product ID, previous value, new value) and create a method that gets called by after_save that creates a ProductAudit with the relevant parameters?

Comment: True, will need to look more into that. Also I found verstal_versions, I haven't managed to make it work for Rails 3 yet, but seems promising. Thanks

Comment: That looks pretty cool!  I hope you manage to get it working.  It certainly looks useful.